# HeidiSQL does not allow me to create a foreign key, what can I do?

Tags: sql, xcode, mariadb, mysql-error-1064, heidisql

I'm trying to create some tables in HeidiSQL, the main key allows me to create it without any problem but when trying to create a foreign key I get error (1064) I would like to know if they could help.

Table 1. Where the main key is located

[image]

Table 2. Where the foreign key should go

[image]

Comment: Can you explain  to us what are the steps followed?

Comment: Please paste your SQL code in your question using the code block feature, instead of putting your code in screenshot images.  Use the icon with the curly braces {} to mark your SQL as "code" when editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in with Root
2. Create the tables
3. fill the tables with the given information
4. Create the main key in id_clientes
5. Create the foreign key in the table t_clientes put in the cell with the same name bearing the main key (id_clientes)

Those are at least the steps I have been given for this task but I will appear error 1064, even if I try to switch to another cell does not allow me the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I believe it will work

```
ALTER TABLE t_clientes
ADD CONSTRAINT id_clientes_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_clientes)
        REFERENCES t_ventas(id_clientes) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Comment: Thank you, for your response... a question... there is a way to create the foreign key without creating the key to index (the green)???

Comment: You can create foreign key without creating the key to index. but the foreign key you declared must be unique.